# Ошибка компилятора C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Ошибка  C1091   ограничение компилятора: длина строки превышает 65535 байт

Можно его как-то устранить без использования strcpy_s ?

Comment: А вам **точно** нужна такая длинная строка на этапе компиляции? Можно поинтересоваться, почему и зачем, может, решение совсем в другом искать можно?

Comment: В этом тексте содержится шрифт в base85. Я просто не хочу таскать с собой файл с шрифтом,а там нужные мне иконки.

Comment: А как ресурс добавить, например?...

Comment: В динамической библиотеке ? У меня не приложение.

Comment: "Распилите" эту вашу строку на куски покороче, в единое целое (если надо) соберите уже во время выполнения. Видимо именно это вы и имели в виду странным упоминанием `strcpy_s`. (Почему именно `strcpy_s`?)

Comment: А почему вы шрифт (то есть по сути бинарные данные) храните в виде текста? Почему бы не хранить бинарные данные как бинарные данные?

Comment: @AnT Потому что  именно этот совет MSDN дает :)

Comment: Храните шрифт отдельным файлом и устанавливайте его в систему соответствующим образом. А так только костыли раскидываете...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Провел такой эксперимент (Visual C++ 2015). Создал массив типа

```
unsigned char sss[] = {

   0x50,0x48,0x51,0x47,0x48,0x55,0x4d,0x45,0x41,0x59, ...
```

и далее - миллион байт. Скомпилировалось на ура.

Преобразуйте свою строку в такой байтовый массив - только и разницы,
что не строка будет, а массив, а обращаться-то все равно можно будет
через указатель :)

Вот, скомпилируйте и запустите:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE * f = fopen("test.cpp","wt");

    fprintf(f,
            "#include <stdio.h>\n"
            "char sss[] = {\n");
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(f,"0x%02x,", rand()%26+'A');
        if (i % 40 == 39) fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    fprintf(f,"};\n"
            "int main() {\n"
            "puts(sss);}\n");
    fclose(f);
    system("cl test.cpp");
}
```